# How to do time-series prediction in the browser

Tags: tensorflow, time-series

I've been trying to find a simple tutorial to take me through using TensorFlow.js to do predictions on a series of values, but I haven't been able to find something simple and based in JS.

I've got a long list of values (to two decimal places), and I'd like to train on a subset of these and test to see if there's a way to predict the next value.  I have over a million values in this set, and they're just simple values in sequence.

Any direction or helpful and simple tutorials would be really appreciated.

Comment: If the goal is to get the predictions rather than learn Tensorflow.js also try traditional Kalman filter and ARIMA approaches, for which libraries also exist. It will run faster. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

> I've got a long list of values (to two decimal places), and I'd like to train on a subset of these and test to see if there's a way to predict the next value.

The first thing comes to mind is sequence models, I think this will be useful for you, see [Real-time Performance RNN in the Browser](https://magenta.tensorflow.org/performance-rnn-browser)